# developing an app together

Tags: sharing

I'm using google-app-engine on Java to develop a web application with a friend. Every time we make changes in the code, we have to manually send each other the fixed .java file through email and tell each other what changes have been made. I would love to see if there is a more convenient way for us to make changes in our code and share. thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

Subversion is popular, though GIT is gaining popularity these days.

There are [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software) other [SCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) tools out there and many hosted services.

There are many benefits to using a SCM apart from being able to easily share code (you have a history of your codebase and can revert changes, see who changed what and more).

I wouldn't consider a programmer to be a professional if they do not use SCM.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [source code version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) like [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/).

For comparison see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software

The best solution will be to host in on a server accessible by all developers, so that any of you of you can access the repository without notifying the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a project hosting site. like

http://www.code.google.com/

Comment: But only if your project is intended to be open source.